# PrimeFaces inputTextarea is not auto resizable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to make resizeable inputTextarea in dataTable. Written next xhtml by the [Primefaces-Users-Guide](https://ru.scribd.com/document/98840317/Primefaces-Users-Guide-3-3) and [ShowCase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml)

```
                        <p:dataTable id="valueSelection" var="value"
                            value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
                            <p:column headerText="Test" >
                                <h:inputTextarea value="#{car.brand}"  autoResize="true" cols="38"
                                                 style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none;"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

But when the text in inputTextarea is only one row, the height is for two row.
[image]

In FireFox the element row is (without class):

```
<textarea id="mainform:tabPanel:valueSelection:1:j_idt132" name="mainform:tabPanel:valueSelection:1:j_idt132" cols="38" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none;" disabled="disabled">STEVE6666</textarea>
```

And the generated css is (without height):

```
element {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    resize: none;
}
```

Why primefaces does not generate height in css and class attribute in html tag?

Comment: Uhhhhmmmmmm PLEASE check which inputText component you are **actually** using... Oh and you refer to the PF 3.3 manual. We are at 6.3 almost

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you for response. The inputText component is actually used from mvn dependency - com.sun.faces | jsf-api | 2.1.16. The PrimeFaces version is 6.1.

Comment: Please read the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you used `h:inputTextarea`, which is the default implementation of the component in JSF, and thus, does not support auto resize.

Try to use `p:inputTextarea`, which is the PrimeFaces one, and check if the desired behavior will happen.